# Visual Studio debugger "Just My Code" optimization excludes all my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2019 for a C# app.

I reopened and old project of mine, and during debugging, my breakpoints would not be hit showing the message "no symbol have been loaded for this document".

Under the modules windows, I found one of mine -> "Symbol Load Information"; it reads

> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

I can load it manually, or disable "just my code", but I want to do neither.

Why are my files now excluded by the "just my code"? How could I mark these files as mine again?

Comment: Are you building for Release or Debug?

Comment: Quote: *The .NET debugger considers optimized binaries and non-loaded .pdb files to be non-user code*.  So "module is optimized" tells you why the breakpoints don't work.  It gets optimized in the Release build with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Suppress JIT optimization" unticked.  This option's default got changed in recent VS versions, now unticked, which is perhaps why you found it doesn't work like it used to.  Debugging the Debug build is best.

Comment: I was building debug, by mistake. Thanks for your help, most obvious is often the right answer...

Comment: @sayanel Hans Passant's comment was helpful. I posted Hans Passant's comment as an answer, you can mark it so it helps more people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is quoted from Hans Passant:

Quote: The .NET debugger considers optimized binaries and non-loaded .pdb files to be non-user code. So "module is optimized" tells you why the breakpoints don't work. It gets optimized in the Release build with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Suppress JIT optimization" unticked. This option's default got changed in recent VS versions, now unticked, which is perhaps why you found it doesn't work like it used to. Debugging the Debug build is best.